# Get data from Excel-cell using SQL query in Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I've been looking for a way to use an SQL-query in EXCEL with the posibility for the user to input data in an excel-cell as a part of the query.

The query works fine in MS SQL Server Managment Studio

But, i would like that the "set @orgnr = " points to a cell in the worksheet.

The Query looks like this:

```
enter code here
declare @orgnr as varchar(9)

set @orgnr = 123123123

select rating, COUNT(distinct f.dunsnr) as 'Revisjonsklienter', COUNT(distinct db_saksnr) as 'Antall saker', case when SUM(belop) IS null then 0 else SUM(belop) end as 'Sum beløp'
from t_foretak f join t_foretakverv fv on f.dunsnr = fv.dunsnr and kode in (30) and fv.offnr = @orgnr and fv.aktiv_til = 111111111
left join t_foretaknavn fn on f.dunsnr = fn.dunsnr and fn.aktiv_til=111111111
left join t_rating_data r on r.dunsnr = f.dunsnr and r.aktiv_til = 111111111
left join t_beta b on b.dunsnr = f.dunsnr 
and b.type in ('AB','AO','AR','AV','DO','FG','GF','HE','HF','ID','IN','IS','KR','LT','MF','MI','NR','RS','SO','TG','TK','TL','TP','UA','UB','UL','UP') 
and b.aktiv_til = 111111111
where f.aktiv_til = 111111111 and fn.navn_type = 1 
group by rating
order by 
case rating when 'AAA' then 0
              when 'AA' then 1                         
              when 'A' then 2
              when 'AN' then 3
              when 'B' then 4
              when 'C' then 5
              when 'IKKE RATET' then 6
              when 'INGEN-RAT' then 7
              when 'KONKURS' then 8
              when 'TVANGSOPPL' then 9
              when 'LIKVIDERT' then 10
End
```

Comment: Have you ever thought of using Power Query? You can directly link the database to the Excel spreadsheet and have user make calls back to the DB: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6E92E2F4-2079-4E1F-BAD5-89F6269CD605

Comment: Yes, but i have the same problem in Power Query.
I want the user to be able to select search-criteria, "@orgnr", in the query without fiddelin in the SQL-code.

Comment: It is easy for you to custom design the excel so the users can select a search criteria. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gK2yBpiITvI  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95dd4361-cffb-4b12-820a-85c3d041db3e/power-query-query-with-parameter-from-a-cell?forum=powerquery